# Too much time taken to GET a local json file using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, handlebars.js, getjson

I am using the `getJSON` function to fetch a local json file (to pass that data to handlebars compile function).

```
$.getJSON('/data.json', function(jsonData) 
      // work with jsonData 
});
```

However, the time taken to fetch a file seems too long. It's 1.84s. Here is a screenshot from chrome dev tools:

[image]

Is this normal ? Any way I can reduce this time?

Comment: Well, that obviously depends on what type of effort is required to generate the data and the resources that are available to the generating process. Do you have any more details about the data source?

Comment: @MasterAM It's just a simple .json file in the same directory as the the page on which the script is running. No server involved.

Comment: I would try asking at serverFault.